# Change of Variables and Expectation of Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Given that we know about random variable X and its probability density function and it's expectation is E(X). We know that when we calculate E(AX+B) we get AE(X)+B.

But when I did change of Variables, assumed Y=AX+B, and computed its probability density function it came out to be 1/A times the pdf of X.
So According to me, when we calculate expectation of X i.e E(AX+B) we have to integrate Y*probability density of Y.. which gives the expectation as E(X)+B/A[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTEV4.jpg)

Comment: why is $ \frac{d}{dy}F_{X}\left(\frac{y-B}{A}\right)=\frac{1}{A}f_{X}\left(x\right) $ ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be fx((y-B)/A).1/A

Comment: Thanks.. got it now

Answer (score 2):

This equation is wrong:

$$\mathfrak{f}_y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}(f_y(y))=\frac{d}{dy}\left(f_x\left(\frac{y-B}{A}\right)\right)=f_x(x)\cdot \frac{1}{A}$$

You accidentally turned $(y-B)/A$ into $x$ in the last step. Instead, it should be

$$\mathfrak{f}_y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}(f_y(y))=\frac{d}{dy}\left(f_x\left(\frac{y-B}{A}\right)\right)=\mathfrak{f}_x\left(\frac{y-B}{A}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{A}$$

Thus, we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \int y\mathfrak{f}_y(y)dy \\
&= \int y \mathfrak{f}_x\left(\frac{y-B}{A}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{A}dy \\
&= \int (Ax+B) \mathfrak{f}_x(x)dx \\
&= A \int x\mathfrak{f}_x(x)dx + B\int \mathfrak{f}_x(x)dx \\
&= A\mathbb{E}[X] + B\cdot 1 \\
&= A\mathbb{E}[X]+B
\end{align*}
$$

as expected. Notice that the $1/A$ goes away when changing the integral from $dy$ to $dx$ because $x=(y-B)/A$, so $dx=(1/A)\cdot dy$.

Comment: Thank you very much..